# Understanding universal restriction of a concept in Description Logic (DL)

Tags: first-order-logic, description-logic

I am trying to understand the following **Passage** from a [DL tutorial](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4089.pdf)  in terms of First Order Logic (FOL).

**Passage**

> To represent the set of individuals all of whose children are female, we use the universal restriction
>
> `∀parentOf.Female`        (16)
>
> It is a common error to forget that (16) also includes those individuals that have **no children at all**.

I take (16) to mean "*if an individual has children, then those children are all female*".  My FOL representation of (16) is:

`∀x∀y(parentOf(x,y) → Female(y))` (1)

My rational for this translation is that the implicit variable `x` represents the set of individuals being defined by the role `parentOf`. I assume `x` is universally quantified. The variable `y` represents female children, which I believe is called the successor of `x` in DL terminology, it is explicitly universally quantified in DL.

My FOL representation of "*individuals that have no children at all*" in FOL is:

`∀x∀y  ¬(parentOf(x,y))` (2)

My interpretation of the **Passage**, in FOL terms, is that if (2) holds then (1) holds. This is because the antecedent of (1) is false in this case.

Is my interpretation of the **Passage** correct?

Are my translations correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### About your formula (1)

If you say

```
∀x∀y(parentOf(x,y) → Female(y))
```

or, equivalently

```
∀y((∃x parentOf(x,y)) → Female(y))
```

you mean that every `x` can only have female children. But for stating this in DL you need concept inclusion, that is:

```
⊤ ⊑ ∀parentOf.Female
```

that means "the range of role `parentOf` is included in concept `Female`".

Concept and role inclusions are intensional **assertions**, i.e., axioms specifying general properties of DL constructs.

Instead, DL's restrictions are **not** assertions, but constructs like concepts. So they are not used to state properties that are valid for every individual of the ontology. Like, when you say `C⊓D`, you are not stating that all the individuals of your ontology are instances of `C` and `D`, but you are simply "collecting" only the individuals that are instances of `C` and `D` at the same time.

Therefore, the formula `∀parentOf.Female` just wants to "catch" all the `x` such that, if `x` is parent of `y`, then `y` is `Female`. More formally, its semantics is the following:

```
{x|∀y (parentOf(x,y) → Female(y))}
```

### About your formula (2)

Analogously, the semantics of "individuals that have no children at all" is a set of individuals too:

```
{x|∀y ¬parentOf(x,y)}
```

or equivalently

```
{x|¬∃y parentOf(x,y)}
```

Indeed, you are collecting all the individuals that have no children, and not stating that all the individuals have no children.

### Conclusion

You say right: "if (2) holds then (1) holds". The point is that neither (2) nor (1) (necessarily) hold.

Since you are working with sets, you should not reason in terms of *logical inference* but of *set inclusion*.

Therefore, the correct interpretation of the **Passage** is not

> if `∀x∀y ¬(parentOf(x,y))` then `∀x∀y(parentOf(x,y) → Female(y))`

but

> `{x|∀y ¬parentOf(x,y)}` is a subset of `{x|∀y (parentOf(x,y) → Female(y))}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems I should be thinking in terms of sets. I am unsure of the syntax ^-  just before the ⊑ in ∃parentOf^- ⊑ Female.

Comment: You're right, the proper formula is `⊤ ⊑ ∀parentOf.Female`. Thank you!